# How to create an NSArray in a for loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, sdk

How do I shorten the following code by executing it in a for loop?

```
NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"z1.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"z2.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"z3.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"z4.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"z5.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"z6.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"z7.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"z8.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"z9.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"z10.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"z11.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"z12.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"z13.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"z14.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"z15.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"z16.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"z17.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"z18.png"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"z19.png"],
                         nil];
```

Comment: Checkout `NSMutableArray` [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The magic is in `NSMutableArray` as @Teak mentioned in the comment. In fact, there is a mutable version for all container classes like, like `NSString`, `NSDictionary`, `NSSet`, etc.

```
NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSUInteger i = 1; i <= 19; i++) {
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"z%d.png", i];
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
}
```

Comment: Depending on how big those images are, you might not want to use an autoreleased array.

Comment: Yeah, true. I prefer the autoreleased and auto-managed versions as a starter until it is clearly proven that I'm having memory issues with that particular object staying alive for the length of the current run-loop.

Comment: Instead of dealing with release/autorelease i would STRONGLY RECOMMEND that you just use apple's ARC to handle your memory management. Its painless and actually really robust and efficient.

Answer (score 4):

If you dont mind to stop the animation you can do the following since iOS 5:

```
UIImage *myAnimatedImage = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"z" duration:10];
```

It will search for images and add numbers to it automaticly. Caveat is that you can not stop the animated Image like in a `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to make use of an `NSMutableArray`. However, you can place the result in an `NSArray` at the end if immutability is important.

```
NSMutableArray *workingArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_IMAGES; i++) {
    [workingArray addObject:[UIImage imageName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"z%d.png", i]];
}

NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithArray:workingArray];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:19];

for(int i = 1; i <=19; i++)
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"z%d.png, i]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSMutableArray *arrImage = [NSMutableArray  arrayWithCapacity:0];
 for(int i = 1; i<= 19;i++)
 {
    [arrImage  addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"z%d.png",i]]];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You load an animated UIImage, which handles the file names for you. Then you retrieve the images array from it.

`NSArray* images = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"z" duration:1].images;`